# Vaadin with Spring and Multiple Users

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have a really strange Problem with my new Vaadin Project.
If I start my Application and log in with a User, then switch the Browser and open the Site again, it seems that the Sessions will be shared. I have the same Content in both Windows.

I readed a few forum Posts about this Problem, all they say don´t open the App in the same Browser. Ok, i startet a VM, but, the same Problem. Or, remove all static variables from the context. I have done that, now using the ThreadLocal-Pattern.

I have absolutly no idea whats wrong. What I believe is that the Spring Context kills Vaadin, has anyone ever had this experience with Vaadin and Spring?

To bring Spring and Vaadin togehter I use the Spring Intgration Addon for Vaadin by Nicolas Frankel (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/spring-integration)

I will post my Application Code for further investigation.

===================

The Vaadin Application Class:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements HttpServletRequestListener    {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2067470624065324231L;

private static ThreadLocal<MainApplication> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<MainApplication>();

private Window mainWindow;

//Viewmanager
private ViewManager viewManager;

private Professor professor;

//DAO Classes and Bean Setter´s
ProfessorDAO professorDAO;
QuestionDAO questionDAO;
AnswerDAO answerDAO;
AnsweredDAO answeredDAO;
QRCodeDAO qrCodeDAO;

public void setProfessorDAO(ProfessorDAO professorDAO) {
    System.out.println("Setting ProfessorDAO!");
    System.out.println(professorDAO.toString());
    this.professorDAO = professorDAO;
}

public void setQuestionDAO(QuestionDAO questionDAO) {
    System.out.println("Setting QuestionDAO!");
    System.out.println(questionDAO.toString());
    this.questionDAO = questionDAO;
}

public void setAnswerDAO(AnswerDAO answerDAO) {
    System.out.println("Setting AnswerDAO!");
    System.out.println(answerDAO.toString());
    this.answerDAO = answerDAO;
}

public void setAnsweredDAO(AnsweredDAO answeredDAO) {
    System.out.println("Setting AnsweredDAO!");
    System.out.println(answeredDAO.toString());
    this.answeredDAO = answeredDAO;
}

public void setQrCodeDAO(QRCodeDAO qrCodeDAO) {
    System.out.println("Setting QRCodeDAO!");
    System.out.println(qrCodeDAO.toString());
    this.qrCodeDAO = qrCodeDAO;
}

public ProfessorDAO getProfessorDAO() {
    return professorDAO;
}

public QuestionDAO getQuestionDAO() {
    return questionDAO;
}

public AnswerDAO getAnswerDAO() {
    return answerDAO;
}

public AnsweredDAO getAnsweredDAO() {
    return answeredDAO;
}

public QRCodeDAO getQrCodeDAO() {
    return qrCodeDAO;
}

//Currently logged in Professor.
public Professor getProfessor() {
    return professor;
}

public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
    this.professor = professor;
}



public static void setInstance(MainApplication application){
    threadLocal.set(application);
}

public ViewManager getViewManager() {
    return viewManager;
}

public void setViewManager(ViewManager viewManager) {
    this.viewManager = viewManager;
}

public static MainApplication getInstance(){
    return threadLocal.get();
}

public MainApplication() {
}

@Override
public void init() {
    setInstance(this);

    setTheme("crs");

    mainWindow = new Window("CRS -- Classroom Response System");
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);

    viewManager = new ViewManager(mainWindow);

    viewManager.switchScreen(LoginScreen.class.getName(), new LoginScreen());


    //mainWindow = new MainWindow("CRS -- Classroom Response System");
    //setMainWindow(mainWindow);


}


public void onRequestStart(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    MainApplication.setInstance(this);

}

public void onRequestEnd(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    threadLocal.remove();

}
```

The web.xml:

```
<display-name>CRSServer</display-name>


<context-param>
    <description>
    Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CRS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ch.frankel.vaadin.spring.SpringApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>applicationBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.frontend.MainApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <description>
        Application widgetset</description>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.widgetset.CrsserverWidgetset</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CRS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The Spring Context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs" />
<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
    </property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crs"></property>
    <property name="username" value="crs"></property>
    <property name="password" value="password"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Professor</value>
            <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Answer</value>
            <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Answered</value>
            <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Question</value>
            <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.QuestionQRCode</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- VAADIn Startup -->
<bean id="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.frontend.MainApplication" class="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.frontend.MainApplication">
    <property name="answerDAO" ref="answerDAO" />
    <property name="answeredDAO" ref="answeredDAO" />
    <property name="professorDAO" ref="professorDAO" />
    <property name="qrCodeDAO" ref="qrCodeDAO" />
    <property name="questionDAO" ref="questionDAO" />
</bean>



<bean id="professorDAO" class="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.implementation.ProfessorDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Professor</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="questionDAO" class="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.implementation.QuestionDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Question</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="qrCodeDAO" class="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.implementation.QRCodeDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.QuestionQRCode</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="answerDAO" class="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.implementation.AnswerDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Answer</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="answeredDAO" class="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.implementation.AnsweredDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Answered</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="deviceDAO" class="cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.implementation.DeviceDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.database.entity.Device</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

If you need any further classes please let me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Vaadin + Spring but without Spring Integration Addon.
I think that the problem is that you are not creating a new Vaadin applicationBean for the new user that requests the application.

In my app, I pass the applicationBean in web.xml. My Vaadin application is annotated with:

**Application Class**

```
@Component(value = "appName")
@Scope(value = "session")
class AppName extends Application {
....
}
```

**WEB.XML**

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationBean</param-name>
        <param-value>appName</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

And for every new session Servlet returns new app.
In your web.xml you pass your vaadin application like this:

**Your WEB.XML**

```
   <init-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>applicationBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>cs.hm.edu.kreipl.crs.frontend.MainApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

So it returns **every time** the same app for all users. And that's what I think causes the problem.